# Text at the top of all contents

Tags: html, css

I have a question ....

In my webpage [here](http://liamrabe-official.weebly.com)

But when you scroll how can i do so the fixed header is on top of all content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`z-index` CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on the element you want to put over the others.

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>   An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.

```
#sticky {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Use 1 or more, depending on the value of the other z-indexed elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use z-index to place your header on top:

```
#sticky{
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
#sticky {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 1200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `z-index` with a large number like this:

```
#sticky {
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
width: 1200px;
margin-top: -15px;
display: inline;
z-index: 99999;  /* added */
}
```

[z-index reference](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)